# Handling errors while iterating a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

The Python CSV module is set up to iterate over the csv object. This is easy when the data is clean. But becomes complicated if you want to capture an error parsing a bad line in the csv file. Is there a way to try: except: handle the error without falling out of the iterating for loop?

Here is what the documentation says to do:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', mode='r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        #do stuff
```

However, if the error occurs when parsing the record during "row in reader", How can I catch the error without bombing the for loop?

The following will catch the error but kills the loop

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', mode='r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    count = 0
    try:
        for row in reader:
            count += 1
            #do stuff
    except:
        print('had and error on record {:d}'.format(count+1) )
```

This is a problem that comes up often in Python. There must be a "pythonic" way to handle errors like this.

Comment: Put `continue` under `except` block.

Comment: Catching the `Exception` in an `except` block, does not mean you will be able to recover from the error and keep going. The best you can do is abort the reading process in most if not all cases. This is because that csv reader has problem "lost track" of where it is in the file it was reading. Ultimately the only solution will be to fix the offending file.

Comment: I got the job done by adding 
     errors='ignore'
as a parameter to the open command.

Comment: Could you add some example CSV rows that are failing to your question using the [edit] button?  It would then be easier to suggest possible solutions on how to handle them correctly.